# Чи є слова «жити» та «мешкати» синонімами?

Tags: синоніми, різниця-між-словами

Мене цікавить використання цих дієслів **разом з позначенням місця**. Бо після прочитання кількох матеріалів у ЗМІ склалося враження, що жодної різниці між ними немає. Ось кілька прикладів:

- З [розслідування](http://hromadske.ua/posts/taemni-statki-zastupnika-holovi-sbu-pavla-demchini) «Громадського телебачення»:

  > Так, станом на 2015 рік високопосадовець офіційно **мешкав** *у відомчому гуртожитку СБУ.*

  > Дівчина на ім’я Юлія навчається в Києві та **живе** *в гуртожитку.*
- [Стаття](http://www.dw.com/uk/%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%94-%D1%85%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0/a-37901878) «Deutsche Welle»:

  > Місцеві жителі, які **мешкають** *на лінії
  > фронту* між українськими військовими та бойовиками невизнаних
  > "республік", беззахисні перед ним. Іван Полянський також **живе**
  > *у цій зоні.*
- [Матеріал](http://www.radiosvoboda.org/a/27892246.html) «Радіо Свобода»:

  > Але, якщо не за грішми,
  > а, скажімо, хочеться **мешкати** *у Європі*, і **жити**
  > *у державі*, де система функціонує краще, ніж в Україні, то
  > Німеччина цілком цікавий варіант.

Answer (score 9):

Я бачу дві відмінності:

1. Як [правильно сказав Oleg](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1000/4), «жити» має значно більше значень, ніж «мешкати» і не завжди застосовується саме і лише для зазначення місця проживання. Хоча Ви зазначили, що Вас цікавить лише вживання разом з позначенням місця — навіть в такому випадку є нюанси. У випадку дієслова «мешкати» основною інформацією повідомлення має бути місце проживання. Що ж до інших видів інформації:

   - Деякі види іншої інформації взагалі несумісні зі словом «мешкати»:

     > Він жив щасливим життям вільної людини, що виконала всі обов'язки перед суспільством, у своїй старенькій квартирі за адресою вул. Герцена, 28, кв. 1.

     Тут, очевидно, головною інформацією є життєвий стан людини, а вказане місце проживання — вторинне, «задля галочки».

     > <s>Він мешкав щасливим життям вільної людини, що виконала всі обов'язки перед суспільством, у своїй старенькій квартирі за адресою вул. Герцена, 28, кв. 1.</s>

     Так ми сказати взагалі не можемо.
   - Деякі види іншої інформації встрачають частину своїх конотацій:

     > Він живе з Івановою у квартирі на Фрунзе.

     Це речення може передавати два можливі повідомлення: або що суб'єкт перебуває з об'єктом у стосунках, любовному чи статевому зв'язку (жити 5), а місце проживання — вторинна інформація; або що це лише зазначення місця їх проживання. Інтерпретація залежить від контексту і, можливо, розділових знаків. Наприклад, «він живе з Івановою, у квартирі на Фрунзе» робить трішки більший акцент на «з Івановою».

     > Він мешкає з Івановою у квартирі на Фрунзе.

     Це суто зазначення місця проживання. Така побудова фрази, звісно, не означає, що «він» не перебуває з Івановою у статевих стосунках або що слухач не буде щось з цього приводу «додумувати». Але сама фраза нейтральна і таких натяків не містить (всі домислювання — на совісті слухача). Навіть постановка коми чи взагалі прибирання другої частини в мене особисто створюють враження дрібної помилки або того, що «Іванова» зазначена як орієнтир місця (щось типу «він живе в Іванової / там же, де Іванова — а, де Іванова живе, ти вже знаєш») — а не що мовець намагався сповістити про їхній (перед)шлюбний стан.
   - Деякі обставини при керуванні словом «мешкати» набувають вужчого змісту:

     > Він щасливо жив у своїй квартирі на Десятинній.
     >
     > Він щасливо мешкав у своїй квартирі на Десятинній.

     - У другому випадку створюється враження, що він щасливий саме тому, що живе там. Можливо, в нього були якісь великі проблеми з купівлею цієї квартири чи отриманням права жити там, чи в нього хотіли її відібрати злочинці або органи влади, чи можливість жити там через інші невідомі без контексту причини коштувала йому великих зусиль.
     - У першому випадку він просто щасливий, невідомо через що, цілком можливо, що через щось, зовсім непов'язане із місцем проживання.
2. Взагалі, «мешкати» більш сухе і формальне.

   В тому числі його значно важче застосовувати в переносних значеннях:

   > Він жив у світі своїх мрій.
   >   <s>Він мешкав у світі своїх мрій.</s>

   Теоретично другий варіант теж можливий, але накладає значно жорсткіші умови на контекст і, мабуть, змінює стиль тексту. (По-моєму, другий варіант вийде застосувати лише в якомусь надліричному, надпоетичному тексті, де «у світі своїх мрій» цілком передбачувана фраза і дозволяється значно вищий рівень переносності/метафоричності.)

Answer (score 5):

На перший погляд комусь може здатися, що ці слова мають дуже багато спільного, але варто зазирнути до [словника](http://sum.in.ua/s/meshkaty),..

Мешкати:

> МЕ́ШКАТИ, аю, аєш, недок.
>
> 1. Жити, проживати (у певному приміщенні). Вілла, де я мешкаю, в кращій, тихішій і теплішій частині острова (Михайло Коцюбинський, III,
>      1956, 406); У тім самім домі, де мешкала учителька Марія, була на
>      піддашші маленька.. комірочка, в котрій Тарас помістився з сестрами
>      (Степан Ковалів, Світ.., 1960, 63); Оскільки в гуртожитку мешкали
>      тільки нежонаті, на першому поверсі містилися їдальня та майстерня для
>      лагодження одягу (Микола Руденко, Вітер.., 1958, 107); //  Жити (в
>      гнізді, лігві і т. ін. — про тварин, птахів). Полетів горобчик питати,
>      де сова сидить; сказали йому, що вона в сухому дубі в дуплі мешкає
>      (Леся Українка, III, 1952, 481).
> 2. рідко. Жити, проживати у певній місцевості, місці. Мешкають [нащадки запорожців] по багнючих [багнистих] місцях та захлюпаних
>      селах славетної на все царство Полтавщини (Панас Мирний, IV, 1955,
>      367).

[Жити](http://sum.in.ua/s/Zhyty):

> ЖИТИ, живу, живеш, недок.
>
> 1. Бути живим, існувати; протилежне помирати, вмирати. Він не хоче вмирати. Він хоче жити (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 367); Шумить
>      жито, співа, Заохочує жить (Павло Тичина, I, 1957, 7);  * У
>      порівняннях. Степ.. цвіте, ніби живе й дише (Нечуй-Левицький, III,
>      1956, 314).
> 2. Перебувати, проживати де-небудь. Був собі дід та баба. З давнього давна, у гаї над ставом, Удвох собі на хуторі жили (Тарас Шевченко, I,
>      1951, 311); У хаті жила Кармелева дружина з дочкою (Марко Вовчок, I,
>      1955, 364); Петрик жив з мамою під самісіньким лісом (Василь Кучер,
>      Пов. і опов., 1949, 269).
> 3. Проводити життя в якийсь спосіб. Жили собі [Максим та Явдоха] тихо та мирно (Панас Мирний, II, 1954, 136); Живе наша сім'я Весело, багато
>      (Григорій Бойко, 3 Дон. краю, 1952, 75); //  з чого, на що. Мати за
>      джерело свого існування. Скотинку попродала [удова] і стала собі з
>      копійки жити (Квітка-Основ'яненко, II, 1956, 422); Бажаєва.. живе на
>      пенсію, ощадна, запопадлива, клопотлива (Леся Українка, III, 1952,
>      718). ♦ Жити вовками — жити відокремлено від колективу, самотньо,
>      замкнуто. Вийшов закон про зселення хуторів. Закон хороший,
>      правильний. Не жити ж людям вовками поза селами, самотньо, як на
>      висилці (Юрій Збанацький, Єдина, 1959, 22); Жити мов (як, наче і т.
>      ін.) у бога за дверима (за пазухою) — жити в достатках, без усяких
>      турбот. Староміські жили мов у бога за дверима (Іван Франко, III,
>      1950, 66); Жити не по кишені — жити невідповідно до своїх достатків.
>      Пан Г. дуже багато програє грошей в карти і взагалі живе не по кишені
>      (Збірник про Кропивницького, 1955, 61); Жити паном [діло] — жити без
>      усяких турбот. Мірошник паном діло жив (Євген Гребінка, I, 1957, 69);
>      Жити по правді (правдою) — жити чесно, не порушуючи усталених норм
>      співжиття. Завжди він говорив їм: «Живіть з правдою і по правді»
>      (Михайло Стельмах, I, 1962, 384); Часто й густо вона думала: чи вже
>      людям не можна жити правдою?.. (Панас Мирний, I, 1949, 295); Жити як
>      сир у (в) маслі — жити забезпечено, в достатках. До кого ж ласкава ся
>      доля лукава, Такий живе як сир в маслі (Пісні та романси українських
>      поетів.., II, 1956, 7).
> 4. чим. Вважати що-небудь основним у житті, бачити в чомусь смисл життя. Живу твоїми листами, цілую тебе в думці (Михайло Коцюбинський,
>      III, 1956, 146); — Тільки й живу надією, ..що скоро вернуться наші
>      (Антон Хижняк, Тамара, 1959, 21).
> 5. Перебувати з ким-небудь у певних стосунках, вести спільне життя. Розмовляли вони про те, як житимуть укупі (Марко Вовчок, I, 1955,
>      322); — Що ж я тобі пораджу? Маєш жінку, чом з нею не живеш у згоді?
>      (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 49); //  з ким, розм. Бути з
>      ким-небудь у любовному зв'язку. Він [пан] розійшовся з своєю жінкою
>      ..і почав жити з своїми кріпачками-дівчатами (Панас Мирний, V, 1955,
>      334).
> 6. перен. Бути, існувати, мати місце. Потреба краси, що жила в душі Антона, викликала у нього потребу скрізь шукати її, але дійсність
>      давала мало (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955, 285); У віршах М.
>      Рильського.. живе і гаряче хвилюється наш радянський патріотизм,
>      велика любов до рідної землі (Андрій Малишко, Думки.., 1959, 13);
>      Тільки між віттям старих осокорин живе невмирущий легіт (Микола Рудь,
>      Гомін.., 1959, 27); Ленінова мудрість в Партії живе! (Валентин Бичко,
>      Вогнище, 1959, 48).

як ми побачимо, що дієслово "*жити*" має шість значень та лише два з них перетинаються зі словом *мешкати* у значеннях проживати у певному **приміщенні** та  проживати у певній **місцевості**, останнє  у словнику позначене як рідковживане, але з другої половини ХХ сторіччя, словом "*мешкати*" часто стали послуговуватися у значенні "проживати у певній місцевості". Тому можна сказати, що лише у цих значеннях це слова синонімі.

Comment: Взагалі-то в питанні було «**разом з позначенням місця**» — тобто лише про друге значення слова «жити» з СУМ-11.

Answer (score 3):

Одразу ж скажу, що абсолютними синонімами ці слова не є. Ось речення:

> Почни жити своїм життям!

Тут ми не можемо замінити дієслово "жити" на "мешкати".

А тепер щодо вживання цих слів "разом з позначенням місця". Ось цікава [стаття](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine3-16.pdf) Г. Т. Яценка на цю тему:
[image]
[image]

І справді, слово "мешкати" [рідко вживається](https://classes.ru/all-ukrainian/dictionary-ukrainian-explanatory-term-85015.htm) у значенні "жити, проживати у певній місцевості". А на [сайті Політіко](https://politiko.ua/groups/talk_topic?id=59) дається таке пояснення різниці між цими словами:

• «**Жити**» має загальне, найширше значення, і серед інших - перебувати, проживати де-небудь (наприклад: «...дід та баба...удвох на хуторі жили» (Т.Шевченко)).

• «**Проживати**» - жити за місцем прописки (наприклад: «Продавець проживає за адресою: М.Київ, вул.Хмельницького, буд.26, кв.79»).

• «**Мешкати**» - в приміщенні (наприклад: «Сім’я мешкає в трикімнатній квартирі»).

Можна сказати: «Ми живемо в місті Києві» чи «проживаємо в місті Києві (якщо в Києві прописані)».

Comment: О, Ви, здається, єдиний, хто (дуже доречно, по-моєму), згадав ще й третє слово — _проживати_.